# CSS Space between 2 paragraphs not working

Tags: css, textbox

On [my website](http://purewords.com/site11/) on the page "Equipe", I would like some more space between the text "Founder and Managing Director" and the text below. I tried `margin bottom` but doesn't seem to work. Any suggestion?

Note: a `br` would be too much space.

HTML code:

```
<div class="equipe-bio">
    <img src="images/avatar-man.png" width="80" height="80" alt="Picture" />
    <p><span class="bioname">Gregory Yrogerg</span></p>
    <p><span class="biotitle">Founder and managing director</span></p>
    <p>Originaire de Belgique, Gregory vit depuis plus de 20 années en Norvège. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,...</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple fix would be to add the `margin-bottom` to the `<p>` tag, which should achieve your desired effect:

```
<p style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
    <span class="biotitle">Founder and managing director</span>
</p>
```

By default `span` is an inline element. So if you wanted to add a margin to a span, you would have to change the `display` property:

```css
.biotitle {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked! Out of interest, why it doesn't work when I put margin bottom directly in span biotitle?
Thanks,

Comment: @Greg. I added an explanation to the answer. Put simply: you can't add margins to inline properties, and spans are inline by default.

Comment: @Greg. Also, please consider upvoting/accepting my answer if you found it useful. By accepting answers, you make it more likely that members will respond to your questions in the future.